# How to enable Unity's Global Menu in Cinnamon desktop?

Tags: cinnamon

I installed the Cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu 11.10 64bit but the global menu does not show up.
I read that it stills appears and there is a way you can remove it (by uninstalling the menu packages). However, I WANT the global menu on Cinnamon, but it isn't there!

Comment: I would love to know that too. So far I've noticed it might be possible by "making the file manager handle the desktop", but apparently, that option is no longer available. I suppose that's because the appearance of the global menu was then seen as a bug.

The closest thing might be gnome-shell's global menu. Since cinnamon is built on gnome-shell, it shouldn't be a big deal porting the extension to cinnamon (if a port is even needed!).

Comment: I just took a closer look at the gnome3 global menu (which i found it on webudp8's ppa). The extension's structure seems to be identical to the Cinnamon extension structure, but the extension "depends" on some package named "Shell", where Cinnamon applets depend on a package named "Cinnamon", so I just changed the depency, and managed to activate the extension without running into JS errors. Unfortunately, nothing appears on the cinnamon panel, and the application menus stay in their application windows...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In short visit: https://github.com/lestcape/Global-AppMenu Is not available on spices yet.